# How to structure Angular Service method using streams with parameters to select one entity?

Tags: angular, typescript

This should be an easy question as I'm just starting Angular.  The service is using Angular streams.

I successfully created Angular 10 service code and template to display a list of products (DDL interface is a dictionary of label / value pairs):

```
//product.service.ts
getProductsDDL$ = this.http.get<IDDL[]>('https://server/api/products/ddl');

// products.component.html
<ul *ngIf="productsDDL$ | async as ddls">
  <li *ngFor="let d of ddls">{{d.value}} - {{d.label}}</li>
</ul>
```

I plan on adding an html anchor tag `<a>` with a `(click)` event to call a component method with the `d.value` product id as a parameter, then call a service method with the id as a parameter to load the single full product to edit.

```
//products.component.html
getProduct$ = this.http.get<IProduct>('https://server/api/product/{id}');
```

`{id}` is just my visual placeholder for a product id, e.g., `123`.  How does one structure the service method to include a parameter to retrieve one product, used each time the user clicks the `<a>` link in the `*ngIf="product$ | async as product"` manner?  I will then send the populated single product component property to a sub component for CRUD.

I have searched and only found examples of loading all items in a collection, none yet showing service parameters loading a single entity.  I will eventually do full CRUD with this aggregate entity.  Product has a nested array of related products, like flavors of Jello.

Answer (score 2):

The very simple solution would be to take in the parameter as an argument to a method (I'd recommend creating a `Service` for your HTTP-communication, but that's not really a requirement for getting this to work).

Example:

```
getSpecificProduct(id: string) {
   return this.http.get<IProduct>(`https://server/api/product/${id}`);
}
```

And then using it like:

```
//products.component.html
getProduct$ = this.getSpecificProduct('some-id');
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use of the reactivity of Angular + RxJS for establishing a stream that would react to any change of the current product id.

In the service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
class MyService {

  //...

  selectedId$ = new Subject < number > ()

  getSelectedProduct$() {
    return this.selectedId$.pipe(
      switchMap((id) => this.http.get<IProduct>(`https://server/api/product/${id}`))
    }

    selectProduct(id: number) {
      this.selectedId$.next(id);
    }

  }
```

In the component template:

```html
<ul *ngIf="productsDDL$ | async as ddls">
  <li *ngFor="let d of ddls">
    {{d.value}} - {{d.label}} <a (click)="service.selectProduct(d.id)">Select</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="service.getSelectedProduct$() | async as selectedProduct">
   {{selectedProduct | json}}
</div>
```

This way, every time a new product is selected, you get then the `getSelectedProduct$` to emit the network result.

Comment: Exactly what I was just about to suggest. You were faster ;-). Upvoted.